# doubts regarding usage of :: (scope_resolution_operator)

Tags: c++

when I was studying a book on C++, I came across this.
if we declare a class,

```
class student {public:
void func(int v1,int v2)
{
   //some code
}
//some members.
};
```

and use a function with same name out of the class (non-member function) like,

```
void func(int x,inty)
```

and If I wish to call this non-member function in the member function of the above declared class, the syntax would be,

```
//inside the member function...
::func(x,y);
}
```

correct me if I am wrong.otherwise, 
assuming I wrote

```
using namespace std;
```

in the beginning of the program, Is the below code equivalent to previous one?

```
//inside the member function
std::func(x,y);
}
```

and, does the answer change if I use a different namespace other than std?? ie,
provided I use,

```
using namespace abc
```

are the following declarations

```
abc::func(x,y)
```

and,

```
::func(x,y)
```

absolutely equivalent under any conditions or do they change under specific conditions??

Thank you.

Comment: `class student {public:` is the worst possible way to conserve LOC IMO...

Comment: `::func` is `func` of the global `namespace`, `std::func` would be `func` from `std` `namespace`.

Answer (score 2):

> in the beginning of the program, Is the below code equivalent to previous one?
>
> ```
> //inside the member function
>   std::func(x,y);
> ```

No it isn't. Because you preform a **qualified** name lookup. It means you specify exactly in what namespace `func` is to be defined. `std::func`, if it exists, still belongs the the `std` namespace, not the global one.

A `using namespace` directive only makes identifiers available to **unqualified** name lookup, where it's up to the compiler to figure it out. This point is quite intricate, I know, but it's the reason namespaces can be considered useful.

Answer (score 1):

The problem kicks in when you collide the names.

Do not do `using namespace std;`, since it can cause collision problem.

These code are identical:

```
using namespace std;
sort(params...); // Omitted, this will call std::sort
```

---

```
std::sort(params...);
```

And even if you are `using namespace std`, std::sort calls the same functions as long as `std::std` doesn't exist (and defining it from user side is illegal code).

However, `abc::func()` is **not** identical to `::func()`. `::` in the beginning means root namespace, which is the most outside namespace. There's no ambiguity or implicit filling in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The `using namespace` directive allows your code to use stuff that is in the specified namespace. You can even have several of them:

```
using namespace x;
using namespace y;
```

This means that a function call like `func()` will call the function whose code resides either in `x` or in `y` namespace (or, in fact, in the global namespace).

If your code looks like this

```
using namespace x;
using namespace y;
void func(int, int) {... code ...}
```

then the `func` function goes in the global namespace, not in the `x` or `y` namespace. That is, `::func` refers to this function, while `x::func` and `y::func` don't.

To put your code (class, function, etc) in a namespace, use this code:

```
namespace x
{
    void func(int, int) {... code ...}
    class student
    {
        void func(int, int) {... code ...}
    };
}
```

*Then*, if you want to call the `func` that is outside your `class`, you can use `x::func()` or `::x::func()`, but cannot use `::func()`.